What is the difference between using "module" versus "group" and "name" in toml files (gradle catalog)?
I'm migrating my Android project to gradle catalog, for a better management of dependencies. Documentation doesn't make it very clear, or I've missed something, but what is the difference between using these lines in your toml file:
androidx-core = { module = "androidx.core:core-ktx", version.ref = "vCore" }

versus:
androidx-core = { group = "androidx.core", name="core-ktx", version.ref = "vCore" }

I've read several articles about managing dependencies in gradle catalog, and usage seems to be quite random and incosistent. Are there any benefits of using either of those?
Thanks

No, they are exactly the same.
Just like you can use implementation(group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx") or implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx") in a build script.
This is just a question about preference and style.
